# Why a segfault on #define?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, c-preprocessor

I don't understand why my program segfault after `#define` with that :

`if(QProcess::systemEnvironment().filter("toto").size() == 1 )
  if(!QProcess::systemEnvironment().filter("toto").at(0).contains("13"))
    #define tata`

I using this code in another class and he run like a boss :P

The program segfault when the if is false...

I know #define is a precompiler directive and I understand the segfault but why this same code run in my another class with no problem and if my environment variable is changed the program accept the modification.. and I specified that the code has not been recompiled..

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Why the close and down-votes? It may be a simple misunderstanding, but it's a reasonable question and it's obvious from the three lines what that misunderstanding is, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is a precompiler directive, it is parsed and used by the compiler, not at runtime. So it does not obey your `if` conditions. Thus, your `if` is actually conditioning the execution of whatever goes after this code... whatever it is.

Solution: use a boolean variable, not a macro.

```
bool tata = false;
if(QProcess::systemEnvironment().filter("toto").size() == 1 )
    if(!QProcess::systemEnvironment().filter("toto").at(0).contains("13"))
        tata = true;
```

But the details will depend on what you are doing with `tata` in the first place.

Comment: `Solution: use a boolean variable, not a macro.` -> what do you mean?

Comment: @FinalContest: I'm assuming that the macro is used to compile something conditionally with `#ifdef`. If that is the case, and the condition depends on a runtime condition, the proper tool is a boolean variable, not a macro.

Comment: It is hard to tell without an SSCCE for the problem.

Comment: I know #define is a precompiler directive and I understand the segfault but why this same code run in my another class with no problem and if my environment variable is changed the program accept the modification.. and I specified that the code has not been recompiled...

Comment: @user3819278: You are asking why the code that goes after the that, the code you are _not_ showing, crashes. That I cannot tell, It might even be totally unrelated to the copied code!

Comment: my boss will not use boolean variable...

Comment: the crash appear when the if `if(!QProcess::systemEnvironment().filter("toto").at(0).contains("13"))` is false and if is true the program no crash

Comment: @user3819278: Precisely, when the condition is false, then the next statement (the `#define` does not count) is not executed. That's what `if` does, and probably that next statement does something important...